# How to change linux audio input from internal microphone to headset?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, microphone, mx-linux

I'm uisng MX LInux 21 alongside Windows 10 dual boot

But my Linux doesn't detect my headphone my mic as input, it only use my laptop internal mic which is broken and only provide noise. When i connect some audio device through my audio jack when on windows my realtek driver always give me pop up asking what kind of device i'm plugging in, and it solve my problem by choosing headset. So i'm wondering is there any way to do that in linux.

I can understand basic linux command, but not that advanced

My laptop model is Asus X453MA with combo 3.5mm jack
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, use the left/right arrow keys in `alsamixer` to move the red highlight to the third column from the left, which has no volume bar, just the text `Headphon` in yellow. Then try the up/down arrow keys. Does the text change? What options are available? This might be the headphone/headset selector you're looking for.

Second, note that you are currently viewing only the playback (output) settings. To view the mixer settings for inputs, press the <kbd>F4</kbd> key to view the audio capture (input) settings, or alternatively, press the <kbd>F5</kbd> key to view all the mixer settings at once. Note that the mixer can be have more columns than can fit into the window: if so, trying to move past the left/right edges will shift the view.

When the inputs are visible, depending on the exact sound chip model, there might be a word `CAPTURE` under one of the inputs. If there is a different column for the headset input, use the left/right arrow keys to move to it, then press the space key to tell the sound chip that you wish to capture (input) audio from the headset.

Note that there can be two separate volume settings for each microphone: one among the *output* settings, to control how loudly the microphone sound is fed back into your own speakers/headset, and another among the *input* settings to control the volume of the audio that is fed from the microphone into the programs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!
i've done everything you said above but none works, either my mic input produce no sound at all or just static noise.
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/FHyBQjc/Screenshot-2023-03-19-15-13-04.png" alt="Screenshot-2023-03-19-15-13-04" border="0">
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/HP7qZ9r/Screenshot-2023-03-19-15-13-26.png" alt="Screenshot-2023-03-19-15-13-26" border="0">
so far i'm using online mic test for my testing

i forgot to say thiis but my audio output is working fine